# I am sending a request on every input change for searching by keyword, but the responses are not in the right order..How can i fix this?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, request, axios, onchange

I am sending a new request on every change in the input so I can get the data that contains my actual keyword at the moment of typing. When I finish typing, most of the times as a last response I get the one with less letters, which is ofcourse normal because there is more data with the keyword 'a' than 'ab' (for example).

I have tried with async/await in many ways, but it is still the same, maybe i do not use in the right way or maybe i am missing something..

```
        this.setState({ searchInput: event.target.value })
        const searchInput = event.target.value

         axios.get(url + `/search/${searchInput}`)
         .then( res => {
              console.log(res)
              this.setState({
                 autocomplete: res.data.data[0].providers_name,
             })
             if (searchInput.length === 0) {
                 this.setState({ autocomplete: null })
             }
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err)
              this.setState({ autocomplete: null })
         });

    } 


render(){
  return(
  <input type='text' onChange={this.getDataByKeyword} value={this.state.searchInput} />
  )
}
```

in the console I get the responses but in the wrong order..If I type 'abc' the last response is the data with the keyword 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your request *after* state is updated, use callback form of `setState`.

```
this.setState({ searchInput: event.target.value }, () => {
         const searchInput = event.target.value

         axios.get(url + `/search/${searchInput}`)
         .then( res => {
              console.log(res)
              this.setState({
                 autocomplete: res.data.data[0].providers_name,
             })
             if (searchInput.length === 0) {
                 this.setState({ autocomplete: null })
             }
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err)
              this.setState({ autocomplete: null })
         });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you're clearly bombarding the api and you're not giving the server time to respond, a good way to solve this issue and reduce the overhead as well is to setup a [debounce](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) mechanism, that basically means delaying the call when the user finishes to type.

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeout = -1;
  const currentScope = this;
  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(fn.bind(currentScope, ...args), delay);
  }
}
```

...

```
render(){
  return(
  <input type='text' 
    onChange={debounce(this.getDataByKeyword.bind(this), 1000)}
    value={this.state.searchInput}  
  />
  )
}
```